# Find the minimum visit time on tree

Tags: algorithms, graphs, trees

> A tree is provided which has $n$ nodes and each edge of that tree has a certain length. There are $M$ persons on the tree, numbered 1 through $M$. For each valid $i$, person number $i$ starts at time $t_i$ from vertex number $u_i$ and runs straight to vertex number $v_i$ with constant velocity $s_i$. Before time $t_i$, the person is not considered to be present in the tree. So the question is, for each vertex, what is the first time that a person is present at this vertex. Here $n$ and $m$ are of order $10^5$.

Although I have worked out the basic brute force solution, that doesn't work for the original constraints. What would be a better approach for this problem?

Comment: Perhaps you can describe your brute force solution and its complexity.

Comment: I suggest you read through the material at https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/dynamic-programming/info and then spend a little time thinking about how to apply it here.